# Installing driver AWUS036AC Alfa

Tags: drivers

I tried hard to find the solution, I've already read all the topics on this alpha product but my ignorance and my efforts can't solve my "drivers" problem. I took the download from alfa.com.tw for my AWUS036AC (the latest version). Then I found an install.sh, so through the terminal, once I went to the fold, I wrote `chmod +x install.sh` and then `sudo ./install.sh` . The process went wrong, results: Ubuntu can't find the device when I plug it into the USB port.

Could you help me, please?

```
(##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
Decompress the driver source tar ball:
    rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902.tar.gz
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8192CPhyReg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192d_rf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_p2p.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_recv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/wifi.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8192DPhyReg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8723BPhyCfg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_led.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_recv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_bt_mp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/sta_info.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_dm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types_sdio.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192d_cmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_mp_ioctl.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_com_reg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8821a_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/sdio_ops.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_qos.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_com_h2c.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_dm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_io.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/osdep_service_xp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/ethernet.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_sreset.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/sdio_ops_linux.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/if_ether.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/recv_osdep.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8188EPhyCfg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/sdio_osintf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_rf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_recv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types_ce.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_mp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/circ_buf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8192EPwrSeq.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/sdio_ops_xp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_sreset.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8188EPhyReg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_rf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/usb_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_sreset.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_android.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_br_ext.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/osdep_service_ce.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/sdio_ops_ce.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8192EPhyCfg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_pwrctrl.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/ieee80211_ext.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/mlme_osdep.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_sdio.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_ioctl_set.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/basic_types.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/HalVerDef.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8812PhyReg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_cmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_sreset.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192d_recv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/gspi_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_dm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8192CPhyCfg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_cmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types_gspi.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/ip.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/linux/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/linux/wireless.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_dm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types_xp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/pci_ops.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_beamforming.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_led.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_dm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_gspi.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_mlme.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_rf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/sdio_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8723APhyReg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/cmd_osdep.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_recv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_conf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_com_led.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_security.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_recv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_mp_phy_regdef.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192d_led.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/xmit_osdep.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_cmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_dm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8723BPhyReg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_wapi.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/autoconf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_sreset.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_phy.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/HalPwrSeqCmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_data.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_event.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/wlan_bssdef.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192d_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8723PwrSeq.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8812PhyCfg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_event.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_led.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8723BPwrSeq.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_led.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_ht.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8812PwrSeq.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_efuse.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/gspi_ops_linux.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_cmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8192EPhyReg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_recv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_wifi_regd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_eeprom.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_sreset.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8723APhyCfg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/osdep_intf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/custom_gpio.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192d_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_rf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_ioctl_query.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_mlme_ext.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types_linux.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_led.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_odm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_cmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/h2clbk.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_btcoex.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/gspi_osintf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_btcoex.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_version.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/usb_ops.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/usb_vendor_req.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_sreset.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_rf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_rf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8192DPhyCfg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/usb_osintf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_mem.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/ieee80211.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types_pci.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_recv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8188e_rf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/mp_custom_oid.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_led.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192c_xmit.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_tdls.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8821a_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8821APwrSeq.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_byteorder.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/nic_spec.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_cmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_intf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/pci_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_debug.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/osdep_service_bsd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_com_phycfg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_ioctl.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723b_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/usb_ops_linux.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/osdep_service_linux.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_ap.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_vht.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_pg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_ioctl_rtl.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192d_dm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/osdep_service.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192d_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_phy_reg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/byteorder/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/byteorder/big_endian.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/byteorder/little_endian.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/byteorder/generic.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/byteorder/swab.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/byteorder/swabb.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8812a_cmd.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_com.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/Hal8188EPwrSeq.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/gspi_ops.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtw_iol.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8192e_hal.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/pci_osintf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/rtl8723a_pg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/runwpa
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/Kconfig
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/platform_RTK_DMP_usb.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/platform_ARM_WMT_sdio.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/platform_ARM_SUNxI_usb.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/platform_ARM_SUNxI_sdio.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/platform_ops.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/platform_ARM_SUNnI_sdio.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/platform_ops.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/platform/platform_sprd_sdio.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/custom_gpio_linux.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/rtw_cfgvendor.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/wifi_regd.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/os_dep/osdep_service.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_tdls.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_mp.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_ieee80211.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_ioctl_query.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_sreset.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_wapi_sms4.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_eeprom.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_btcoex.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_ioctl_rtl.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_p2p.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_cmd.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_mem.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_debug.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_beamforming.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_io.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_xmit.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_iol.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_security.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_br_ext.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_bt_mp.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_mlme.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_ioctl_set.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_recv.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_wapi.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_rf.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/efuse/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_ap.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_odm.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_pwrctrl.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_wlan_util.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_sta_mgt.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_vht.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/ifcfg-wlan0
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/clean
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/wlan0dhcp
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/led/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/led/hal_usb_led.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_dm.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_com.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_HWConfig.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_debug.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_HWConfig.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_interface.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_reg.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_AntDiv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_RaInfo.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_EdcaTurboCheck.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_AntDect.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_PathDiv.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/PhyDM_Adaptivity.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_CfoTracking.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_ACS.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/Mp_Precomp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DIG.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_ACS.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_AntDect.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_RXHP.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_RaInfo.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_types.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_RegDefine11AC.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/PhyDM_Adaptivity.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/HalPhyRf.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_EdcaTurboCheck.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_precomp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_RegDefine11N.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_AntDiv.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_debug.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DynamicBBPowerSaving.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_RXHP.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_NoiseMonitor.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/phydm_RegConfig8812A.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_MAC.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalPhyRf_8812A.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_RF.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_RF.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/phydm_RTL8812A.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_FW.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_BB.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/Mp_Precomp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/phydm_RegConfig8812A.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_FW.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_MAC.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/phydm_RTL8812A.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalHWImg8812A_BB.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/rtl8812a/HalPhyRf_8812A.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_CfoTracking.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DynamicTxPower.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DynamicTxPower.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_PathDiv.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_PowerTracking.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_PowerTracking.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DIG.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_NoiseMonitor.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_interface.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC/phydm_DynamicBBPowerSaving.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_intf.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_hci/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_hci/hal_usb.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_btcoex.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_dm.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_dm.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_cmd.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_hal_init.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8812PwrSeq.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_sreset.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_mp.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_phycfg.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rf6052.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/Hal8821APwrSeq.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_rxdesc.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/usb/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_xmit.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_recv.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/usb/usb_halinit.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/usb/rtl8812au_led.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/rtl8812a/rtl8812a_xmit.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8812a2Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8821a1Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8812a2Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8821aCsr2Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8723b1Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8723a2Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8192d2Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8192e2Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8723a1Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8821aCsr2Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8188c2Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8192d2Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8723a1Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8192e1Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8723a2Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8192e1Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8723b2Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8723b1Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8188c2Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/Mp_Precomp.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8723b2Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8812a1Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8192e2Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8821a1Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtcOutSrc.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8812a1Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8821a2Ant.h
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/OUTSRC-BTCoexist/HalBtc8821a2Ant.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_com_phycfg.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/hal/hal_phy.c
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/Makefile
rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/led ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-35-generic/build M=/home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902  modules
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic"
  CC [M]  /home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types.h:95:0,
                 from /home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/hal_com.h:384:13: error: ‘file_path’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 extern char file_path[PATH_LENGTH_MAX];
             ^
In file included from include/linux/compat.h:15:0,
                 from include/linux/ethtool.h:15,
                 from include/linux/netdevice.h:42,
                 from /home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/osdep_service_linux.h:35,
                 from /home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
include/linux/fs.h:2553:14: note: previous declaration of ‘file_path’ was here
 extern char *file_path(struct file *, char *, int);
              ^
make[2]: *** [/home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/core/rtw_cmd.o] Errore 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/cacca/Scaricati/AWUS036AC_036EAC_ACH_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.8_12175.20140902] Errore 2
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic"
make: *** [modules] Errore 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
)
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

You can install this driver patched for Ubuntu kernels by running

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

It is available for `wily` and `xenial`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This happens because you use a linux kernel >= 3.20 I think?
I used [this driver](https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU/tree/master) which runs good, the [beta branch](https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU/tree/driver-4.3.22-beta) supports monitor mode (if you need it).